# DDD: Where to put safety checks? Where to put the check if the user is allowed to do this?

Tags: python, domain-driven-design, domain-model

I have a pretty simple domain model. Basically users, companies and groups. A user can add members to a group and remove them. But the user can only do that for his own company.

Where do I put the check that the user is only adding or removing users from his own company?

I've got the Group Aggregate which has 2 methods:

```
class Group:
    def __init__(self, ...):
        self.company = ...
        self.members = ... 

    def add_member(self, new_member):
        if new_member.company != self.company:
            raise ValueError('The user is not in the same company.')

        if new_member in self.members:
            raise ValueError('The user is already a member of this group.')

        self.members.add(new_member)

    def remove_member(self, member):
        if member not in self.members:
            raise ValueError('The user is not a member of this group.')

        self.members.remove(member)
```

Now I have a Group Service method which calls the add_member method:

```
def add_member(data, actor):  # <-- actor is the user that clicked the button in the ui
    group = GroupRepository.find(id=data.id)
    new_member = UserRepository.find(id=data.new_member)

    if group is None or new_member is None:
         raise Exception('Not found')
 
    if actor.company != group.company:  # <-- QUESTION: where should i put this check? 
        raise Exception('Not allowed')  # It is not allowed to edit groups in other companies

    group.add_member(new_member)

    return 'OK'
```

I'm not sure if the check is in the right place. I could move it into the add_member method inside Group and pass actor along. Then all the business logic for adding a member is inside Group, but it feels wrong for Group to care about the actor.

Another problem I see here is the exceptions that this service can throw. Because there a 2 types of exceptions. The first is that the repositories can throw a NotFound Exception and the second is the "Not Allowed" Exception. I feel like the location of where those 2 types of exceptions are thrown should be further apart. Because one type is business related (the Not Allowed) and the other one is not business related.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since groups are strictly partitioned by company (there's a singular `group.company`), it's very odd to have an unscoped `GroupRepository` at all.

Why is it useful for a user from company **A** to be told they don't have permission to add users to a group owned by company **B**? They shouldn't be able to see that **B**'s group exists at all. Why shouldn't both companies be able to have a group with the same name?

I'd expect the code to look more like

```
def add_member(data, actor):  # <-- actor is the user that clicked the button in the ui
    company = CompanyRepository.find(actor.company)
    group = company.groups().find(id=data.id)
    new_member = UserRepository.find(id=data.new_member)

    group.add_member(new_member)

    return 'OK'
```

Just have each of the company, group, member lookups throw if they don't find the requested key. Returning `None` makes everything more complicated. Now your possible exceptions are just

- *UnknownCompany* - shouldn't happen
- *UnknownGroup* - for your company
- *UnknownUser*

and that's it.

Comment: *"Returning None makes everything more complicated."* — in some ways I agree, and in some ways I disagree with that statement. I think in the context of this problem, though, that statement is true.